# The most modern controller chips for a new active LIPO balancer design

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I'm designing an active LIPO balancer for a hybrid power system that recharges from a gas generator, so it needs to be a lot different from a passive type balancer you'd have on a normal battery charger.  For starters, my battery pack (a 12Sx3.3volt battery built from A123 26650 cells - 39.6 total stack voltage) will never (not from the generator anyway) be allowed to charge above more than about 70 percent SOC, and never allowed to drain below about 40 percent SOC before the charging generator comes back on.

Obviously I need the ability to actively and precisely balance the voltages during heavy discharge and charging both, and I'll never get the opportunity to do a top or bottom balance like normal chargers do.  It's worth it to me to spend good money on the best and most efficient design I can do on this balancer so as to lower the fuel consumption of the generator engine.

My current design I'm drawing right now, is based on two chips from Linear Technology.  The first is the LTC 3300-1 balancer controller.  I'll need two of these to do a 12S stack of batteries.  The second chip is the LTC 6804-1 or-2 which is a battery voltage monitor that integrates with the LTC 3300-1.chip. This setup allows me to use tiny, low cost, off-the-shelf flyback transformers I can buy instead of having to make a custom transformer(s).

I will have connect my own micro-controller to this setup and provide my own software to control it, which will be written especially for the charging needs (staying between 40-70 percent SOC) of a series gas/hybrid charging system.  Charging above about 70 percent is too wasteful with gas.

How do I build a Li-Po balancer?
~~~~~~~~~

Meadows did not write the above question - the mods did, so nobody needs to answer.  It won't give me the information I needed anyway.

Please delete this entire thread since it now has no purpose to serve.  And delete my account too.  I have no use for a lame site where you cannot even ask if anyone else makes chips similar to what I'm already using, or if more recent chip designs are already on the market.

You took my already very specific and ON TOPIC question and turned it into something so generalized that there's no point in asking it.

If this was a car forum, people wouldn't be allowed to mention what kind of car they drive.  That's kinda stupid guys.

Comment: This is a fourm and there are rules, try and read the rules *before posting*. SE.EE has high standards. The edit was to help your question not get closed down, which the mods did anyways. Please see this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask if you feel the need to post any other questions on this site.,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is state of the art, using 1 flyback shunt transformer and 2 series switches, but I know I read an alternative patented concept using 2 shunt switches and one series L between cells and endpoints. Potentially cheaper, but I've not seen yet.